# A variety that contains infinitely many points of a line must contains the whole line.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I suppose maybe I should use the Noetherian Normalization, because we can see that a variety is not much different from a linear variety, and for a linear variety, the proposition holds obviously, but I don't know how to prove it clearly.

Comment: This essentially follows from Bezout's theorem, if you are familiar with that.

Comment: What? You don't need Bezout, just that the proper closed subsets of a line are finite collections of points. Anyways, your question is a bit bereft of context - for instance, it's reasonable to assume you're working with affine or projective varieties over a field, but you should say this, because the result is false if you mean quasiprojective varieties.